# items list inside table cell are not well aligned

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment, lists, longtable

I created a table in LaTeX using `longtable`. I need to have lists inside cells. I used `\tabitem` for that matter but I get not well aligned items. Here is my code:

```
\newcommand{\tabitem}{~~\llap{\textbullet}~~}

\begin{longtable}[H]{| m{5cm} | m{5cm}| m{5cm} | }\hline 
%\begin{center}
%\begin{tabular}{ | m{5cm} | m{5cm}| m{5cm} | } 
%\hline
Méthode de validation & Avantages  & Inconvénients \\ 
\hline
Resubstitution Validation &  \tabitem Simple  & \smallskip \tabitem Surapprentissage \\ 
\hline
Hold-out Validation & \tabitem Apprentissage et tests indépendants & \tabitem Réduction des données utilisées pour l'apprentissage et les tests \newline \smallskip \tabitem Grande variance  \\ 
\hline
k-fold cross Validation & \tabitem Estimation précise des performances & \tabitem Petits échantillons d'estimation des performances \newline \smallskip \tabitem Données d'apprentissage chevauchées \newline \smallskip \tabitem Variance de la performance sous-estimée ou degré de liberté de comparaison surestimé
\\ 
\hline
Leave-One-Out Validation cross-validation & \smallskip \tabitem Estimation non biaisée de performance \newline \smallskip \tabitem Haute exploitation de données pour l’apprentissage & \smallskip \tabitem Variance très large
\\ 
\hline
Repeated k-fold cross-validation & \smallskip \tabitem Grand nombre d’estimation de performance & \smallskip \tabitem Chevauchement des données d'entraînement et d'essai entre chaque itération. \newline \smallskip \tabitem  Variance de la performance sous-estimée ou degré de liberté de comparaison surestimé
\\ 
\hline
%\end{tabular}
%\end{center}
\caption{Caractéristiques des méthodes de validation}
%\end{table}
\end{longtable}
```

Here is what I get:

[image]

As you can see, items are not all aligned in the same way (in the third column). How can I aligned all list items?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I prefer the following form of the your table:

[image]

The code for above table has slightly more sophisticated preamble, but table typing is almost the same as in your code shown in question:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{array,booktabs}

% added packages and column definitions
\usepackage{ragged2e}           % for smart align of cells' content
    \usepackage{enumitem}       % for nice list
\newlist{tabitemize}{itemize}{1}% <-- defined new list
\setlist[tabitemize]{nosep,     % <-- new list setup
                     topsep     = 0pt       ,
                     partopsep  = 0pt       ,
                     leftmargin = *         ,
                     label      = $\bullet$ ,
                     before     = \vspace{-0.6\baselineskip},
                     after      = \vspace{-\baselineskip}
                     }
\newcolumntype{I}[1]{>{\RaggedRight\arraybackslash             % <-- for lists in columns
                    \tabitemize} p{#1}<{\endtabitemize}}
\newcommand\mch[1]{\multicolumn{1}{c}{\small\itshape{#1}}}  % <-- for columns headers  

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{@{} >{\RaggedRight}p{4cm} *{2}{I{4cm}} @{}}
  \toprule
\mch{Méthode de validation}
    &   \mch{Avantages}   &   \mch{Inconvénients} \\
  \midrule
Resubstitution Validation
    &   \item simple
        \item effortles
        &    \item Surapprentissage                 \\
    \addlinespace
Hold-out Validation 
    &   \item   Apprentissage et tests indépendants 
        &    \item   Réduction des données utilisées pour l'apprentissage et les tests
            \item   Grande variance                 \\
    \addlinespace
k-fold cross Validation 
    &   \item   Estimation précise des performances 
        &   \item   Petits échantillons d'estimation des performances 
            \item   Données d'apprentissage chevauchées
            \item   Variance de la performance sous-estimée ou degré de liberté de comparaison surestimé               \\
    \addlinespace
Leave-One-Out Validation cross-validation 
    &   \item   Estimation non biaisée de performance 
        \item   Haute exploitation de données pour l’apprentissage 
        &   \item   Variance de la performance sous-estimée ou degré de liberté de comparaison surestimé                       \\
    \addlinespace
Repeated k-fold cross-validation 
    &   \item   Grand nombre d’estimation de performance 
        &   \item   Chevauchement des données d'entraînement et d'essai entre chaque itération.
            \item   Variance de la performance sous-estimée ou degré de liberté de comparaison surestimé               \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Above code with contained comments should be self-explanatory :). If the `longtable` is essential, than

```
\begin{tabular}{@{} >{\RaggedRight}p{4cm} *{2}{I} @{}}
```

replace with

```
\begin{longtable}{@{} >{\RaggedRight}p{4cm} *{2}{I} @{}}
```

and `\end{tabular}` with `\end{longtable}`.

Answer (score 4):

Why don't you use the standard itemize environment in your table?

I tried a smaller example, to illustrate it.  It does not have that much text as your, but I think, that won't hurt.

I also added package `array` and package `booktabs`.  `booktabs` draws those nice lines.  You should not need more than that few lines.  Read the manual of that package.

Here is my example:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\newcolumntype{T}{%
  >{\scriptsize}c}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{@{} *{3}{m{4cm}} @{}}
  \toprule

  \multicolumn{1}{@{}T}{Méthode de validation}
    & \multicolumn{1}{T}{Avantages} 
    & \multicolumn{1}{T@{}}{ Inconvénients} \\ 
  \midrule
  Resubstitution Validation 
    & \begin{itemize}
          \item simple
          \item effortles
          \end{itemize}
    & \begin{itemize}
          \item Surapprentissage
          \end{itemize}\\
  \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

This is the result

[image]

Of course, regardless the solution you are using: you should have at least two \items in every list, otherwise it won't be a list!

Maybe you will load the `enumitem` package.  It is very mighty, to change the various dimensions of any list.