# \tabitem indenting bullets after first line

Tags: tables, indentation, itemize

As one can see the issue is the bullets are not maintaining an indent. [image]

MWE as seen below

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\newcommand{\tabitem}{~~\llap{\textbullet}~~}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}
     \centering
\begin{tabular}{| p{7cm} | p{7cm} |}
    \hline
        \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{Bezier Curves} \\
    \hline
        \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{Properties} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{Disadvantages} \\
    \hline
        \tabitem A\newline
        \tabitem B\newline
        \tabitem C\newline
        \tabitem D \newline & 
        \tabitem E\newline
        \tabitem F\newline
        \tabitem G\\
     \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: See, if http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/347253/items-list-inside-table-cell-are-not-well-aligned can help you. Or see, if `\newcommand{\tabitem}{\textbullet~~}` gives what you looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the command `\newcommand{\tabitem}{\textbullet~~}`.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\newcommand{\tabitem}{\textbullet~~}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}
     \centering
\begin{tabular}{| p{7cm} | p{7cm} |}
    \hline
        \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{Bezier Curves} \\
    \hline
        \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{Properties} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{Disadvantages} \\
    \hline
        \tabitem A\newline
        \tabitem B\newline
        \tabitem C\newline
        \tabitem D  & 
        \tabitem E\newline
        \tabitem F\newline
        \tabitem G\\
     \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

It is simpler to use an `itemize` environment with convenient parameters inside tabular:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[!htb]
     \centering%
     \setlist[itemize]{wide=0.35em, leftmargin = *, itemsep=-3pt, before=\vspace*{-\dimexpr\baselineskip+\partopsep}, after =\vspace*{\dimexpr-\baselineskip+\partopsep}}
\begin{tabular}{| p{7cm} | p{7cm} |}
    \hline
        \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{Bezier Curves} \\
    \hline
        \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{Properties} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{Disadvantages} \\
    \hline
\begin{itemize}
        \item A
        \item B
        \item C
        \item D
\end{itemize}
&
\begin{itemize}
        \item E
        \item F
        \item G
\end{itemize}\\
     \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This is conversion of my comment above to answer.

In the first part of my comment I provide link to 
[my answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/347253/items-list-inside-table-cell-are-not-well-aligned), which can be easily adopted to your case:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}           % for nice list
\newlist{tablist}{itemize}{1}% <-- defined new list
\setlist[tablist]{nosep,     % <-- new list setup
                 topsep     = 0pt       ,
                 partopsep  = 0pt       ,
                 leftmargin = *         ,
                 label      = $\bullet$ ,
                 before     = \vspace{-0.5\baselineskip},
                 after      = \vspace{-\baselineskip}
                 }
\begin{document}
    \begin{table}
        \renewcommand\arraystretch{1.3}
        \centering
\begin{tabular}{| p{7cm} | p{7cm} |}
\hline
    \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{Bezier Curves} \\
\hline
    \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{Properties} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{Disadvantages} \\
\hline
    \begin{tablist}
        \item B
        \item C
        \item D
    \end{tablist}   &   \begin{tablist}
                            \item E
                            \item F
                            \item G
                        \end{tablist}   \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

In the second part of comment I suggest to replace your definition

```
 \newcommand{\tabitem}{~~\llap{\textbullet}~~}
```

(where `rlap{...}` cause your trouble) with

```
 \newcommand{\tabitem}{\textbullet~~}
```

which gives the same result as above MWE. Which suggestion is more appropriate is up to you to decide :)