# Empty line in tabular after enumerate/itemize

Tags: tables, enumerate, itemize, enumitem

My code

```
\documentclass{article}

%\usepackage{enumitem}
%\setlist{nosep}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{|p{5cm}|}
\hline
text top
\begin{itemize}
\item item text
\end{itemize}\\
\hline
\end{tabular}

\begin{tabular}{|p{5cm}|}
\hline
text top
\begin{itemize}
\item item text
\end{itemize}
text bottom\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

produces an empty line in the first tabular under the itemize (also unter an enumerate).

Even using

```
\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlist{nosep}
```

doesn't help.

Comment: Try as a 'rescue':   \end{itemize}\\[-\normalbaselineskip]` in the first `itemize` list

Comment: See, if https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/347253/items-list-inside-table-cell-are-not-well-aligned can help you.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer I get several errors

Comment: perhaps it is just because you simplified the example (a good thing) but a one-column `tabular` doesn't do anything very useful, you could just use a `\parbox`.

Comment: I think Christian inadvertently left off a backtick in his comment and, as a result, a backslash isn't showing. Try `\end{itemize}\\[-\normalbaselineskip]`.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle The problem of course showes up in larger tables

Comment: @Mico thanks. It works. (But I actually don't like rescues...) Maybe someone else can help

Answer (score 4):

May be this setup of `itemize` can help:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlist[itemize]{nosep,     
                 topsep     = 0pt       ,
                 partopsep  = 0pt       ,
                 leftmargin = *         ,
                 after      = \vspace{-\baselineskip}
                 }
\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{|p{5cm}|}
  \hline
  text top
  \begin{itemize}
    \item item text
  \end{itemize}\\
  \hline
\end{tabular}

\begin{tabular}{|p{5cm}|}
  \hline
  text top
  \begin{itemize}
    \item item text
  \end{itemize}\\   % <======
  text bottom\\
  \hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

> [image]

This will affect all occurrences of `itemize` in your document, so if you need this behavior for `tabular`s only, define a new `tabitemize` style like this:

```
\setlist[tabitemize]{nosep,     
                     topsep     = 0pt       ,
                     partopsep  = 0pt       ,
                     leftmargin = *         ,
                     after      = \vspace{-\baselineskip}
                     }
```

and in your tables use `\begin{tabitemize} ... \end{tabitemize}`.

Comment: I like your attempt, but 1) I would remove '[itemize]' since my question concerns itemize and enumerate 2) I would remove 'topsep = 0pt, partopsep  = 0pt, leftmargin = *,' because I see no use 3) The added arrow '% <======' is very important and this makes me not happy with the solution: Add a second column which is higher than the one with itemize. Now it's not possible to continue with the text directly under the itemize. (This problem occurs if you have multiple tabulars in one document or one row ending with an itemize and an other, which doesn't)

Answer (score 4):

Let me convert my comment to answer with customization of answer [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/347253/items-list-inside-table-cell-are-not-well-aligned) to 
this question:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}           % for nice list
\newlist{tablist}{itemize}{1}% <-- defined new list
\setlist[tablist]{nosep,     % <-- new list setup
                 topsep     = 0pt       ,
                 partopsep  = 0pt       ,
                 leftmargin = *         ,
                 label      = $\bullet$ ,
                 after      = \vspace{-\baselineskip}
                 }
\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{|p{5cm}|}
    \hline
text top
    \begin{tablist}
\item item text
    \end{tablist}\\
    \hline
\end{tabular}

\medskip
\begin{tabular}{|p{5cm}|}
    \hline
text top
    \begin{tablist}
\item item text
    \end{tablist}\\ 
text bottom\\
    \hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Point (1,2,) **3** of my comment to AboAmmar's solution applies to your solution as well. I would fix it, by defining `rowEndList` instead of `tablist` and only use it, if the List really ends the row. But this is still a very inflexible solution. Maybe something like `after=if end of row then \vspace{-\baselineskip} else {}` is possible, but I don't really know if this is a good solution. I guess for a nice solution it needs a complete different approach.

Comment: then don't use `list` environments but just simple `\textbulet\ ... \par` or wait to someone who will be able to do magic which you like to have :)

Comment: Actually I didn't know `\textbullet`, but the indentation is missing. So right now since there is no (easy) solution which handles all eventualities, I guess writing `\vspace{-\baselineskip}` exactly where it is needed, is the easiest solution

Comment: @Ben, shorter is write ` \\ ˙after  \end{tabitem}` :) , but dont give up. Consider to ask new question based on one of above answer with request that `after=\vspace{-\baseline}` is in use, when after list is no text in cell. I'm pretty sure that someone know how to test what follow to list.

Comment: Yes, but "Add a second column which is higher than the one with itemize. Now it's not possible to continue with the text directly under the itemize."