# How to fit a table in a two column document

Tags: tables, two-column, landscape, sidewaystable

I have an article that follows this format: https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007/s11554-016-0569-z.pdf. It is a double-column document, where I have a table that I would like to fit in a single column properly either sideways or in a default position. I tried using the sideway method and the landscape method. My problem is that the table is getting pushed to a new page and leaning on the left.

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
    \usepackage{graphicx}
    \usepackage{multirow}
    \usepackage{float}
    \usepackage{siunitx}
    \usepackage{tabularx}
    \usepackage{adjustbox}
    \usepackage{lscape}
    \usepackage{blindtext}
\begin{document}
    \blindtext\blindtext

    \blindtext\blindtext\blindtext\blindtext
    \begin{landscape}
    \begin{table}
    \caption{Table Title}
    \label{label}       
    \begin{tabular}{lllllll}
    \hline\noalign{\smallskip}
    Author & Model & Resolution & Quality & Hz & Spectral Response & Test \\
    \noalign{\medskip}\hline\noalign{\smallskip}
    Authors et al. & Cam 1 & 640 x 480 & 10 & 30Hz & 8-\SI{14}{\micro\metre} & \multicolumn{1}{p{4cm}}{Check 1} \\
    \noalign{\medskip}
    Authors et al. & Cam 2 & 320 × 256 & 20 60Hz & 7.5-\SI{13}{\micro\metre} & \multicolumn{1}{p{4cm}}{Check 2} \\
    \noalign{\medskip}
    Authors et al.  & Cam 3 & 382 × 288 & 30 & 80Hz & 8-\SI{14}{\micro\metre} & \multicolumn{1}{p{4cm}}{Check 3} \\
    \noalign{\medskip}
    Authors et al. & Cam 4 & 640x512 & 40 & 60\/30Hz & 7.5-\SI{13.0}{\micro\metre} & \multicolumn{1}{p{4cm}}{Check 4} \\
    \noalign{\medskip}
    Authors et al. & Cam 5 & 320x240 & 50 & 60Hz & 7.5-\SI{13.0}{\micro\metre} & \multicolumn{1}{p{4cm}}{Check 5} \\
    \noalign{\medskip}
    Authors et al. & Cam 6 & 640x512 & 60 & 60Hz & 7.5-\SI{13.0}{\micro\metre} & \multicolumn{1}{p{4cm}}{Check 6} \\
    \noalign{\smallskip}\hline
    \end{tabular}
    \end{table}
    \end{landscape}
    \blindtext\blindtext
 \end{document}
```

[image]

The above is an example of the huge skip caused by adding the table to the text. Also, I've tried placing the table in a default position but it goes outside the page the way it is currently

[image].

I'd like to set properly the image either using the sideways, landscape method or even using the default placing on my text.

Comment: You could perhaps use `\begin{table*}
... \end{table*}`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Table within twocolumn document](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/368846/table-within-twocolumn-document)