# Text items inside longtable are not vertically aligned

Tags: longtable, enumerate

My question might be similar with this [items list inside table cell are not well aligned](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/347253/items-list-inside-table-cell-are-not-well-aligned), but the solution was not fit in my case.

with this code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt]{article} 
\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry} % changes the margin
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{blindtext}


%% Create a very compact enumerated list environment
\newlist{myenum}{enumerate}{1}
\setlist[myenum]{label=\arabic*., nosep, wide, 
             leftmargin=*, % hanging indentation
             before=\vspace{-0.57\baselineskip},
             after =\vspace{-0.8\baselineskip}} % reducing vertical   space
%---------------------Need to Simplify This-----------------------------%
\newlist{myenum2}{enumerate}{1}
\setlist[myenum2]{label=\alph*), nosep, wide, 
             leftmargin=*, % hanging indentation
             before=\vspace{-0.57\baselineskip},
             after =\vspace{-0.8\baselineskip}} % reducing vertical space
\newlist{myenum3}{enumerate}{1}
\setlist[myenum3]{label=\arabic*), nosep, wide, 
             leftmargin=*, % hanging indentation
             before=\vspace{-0.57\baselineskip},
             after =\vspace{-0.8\baselineskip}} % reducing vertical space
\newlist{myenum4}{enumerate}{1}
\setlist[myenum4]{label=\arabic*., nosep, wide, 
             leftmargin=*, % hanging indentation
             before=\vspace{-0.57\baselineskip},
             after =\vspace{-0.8\baselineskip},
             start=2} % reducing vertical space
\newlist{myenum5}{enumerate}{1}
\setlist[myenum5]{label=\arabic*., nosep, wide, 
             leftmargin=*, % hanging indentation
             before=\vspace{-0.57\baselineskip},
             after =\vspace{-0.8\baselineskip},
             start=3} % reducing vertical space
\newlist{myenum6}{enumerate}{1}
\setlist[myenum6]{label=\arabic*., nosep, wide, 
             leftmargin=*, % hanging indentation
             before=\vspace{-0.57\baselineskip},
             after =\vspace{-0.8\baselineskip},
             start=4} % reducing vertical space
\newlist{myenum7}{enumerate}{1}
\setlist[myenum7]{label=\arabic*., nosep, wide, 
             leftmargin=*, % hanging indentation
             before=\vspace{-0.57\baselineskip},
             after =\vspace{-0.8\baselineskip},
             start=5} % reducing vertical space               

\renewcommand\thesection{\Alph{section}.}
\renewcommand\thesubsection{\arabic{subsection}.}
%% Re-format the font size of "the section"
% {11} is the desired font size
% {15} is the vertical spacing, perhaps refers to 1.5 lines?
% \selectfont is for un-bold the sub-section
\titleformat{\section}
{\normalfont\fontsize{11}{.5em}\bfseries}{\thesection}{.5em}
    {}
\titleformat{\subsection}
{\normalfont\fontsize{11}{.5em}\selectfont}{\thesubsection}{.5em}
    {}
\titlespacing % starred version: first paragraph is not indented
{\subsection} % <command>
{0em} % <left>
{.4em} % <before-sep>
{.3em} % <after-sep>

\setlength\parindent{1cm} 

% Avoid hypenation (breaking sentences in paragraph)
\tolerance=1
\emergencystretch=\maxdimen
\hyphenpenalty=10000
\hbadness=10000

\begin{document}
%------------------------------Section D---------------------------------------------%
\section{Some Text Here}
\begin{longtable}{@{}p{0.3\textwidth}cp{0.65\textwidth}}
%% Subsection 1
\begin{myenum} \item Some Text Here \end{myenum} & : & \blindtext \\
%% Subsection 2
\begin{myenum4} \item Some Text Here \end{myenum4} & : & \blindtext \\
%% Subsection 3
\begin{myenum5} \item Some Text Here \end{myenum5} & : & \begin{myenum3}
\item Some Text Here;
\item Some Text Here;
\item Some Text Here;
\item Some Text Here;
\item Some Text Here;
\item Some Text Here.
\end{myenum3}\\
%% Subsection 4
\begin{myenum6} \item Some Text Here \end{myenum6} & : &   \begin{myenum2} 
\item \blindtext; 
\item \blindtext;  
\end{myenum2}\\
%% Subsection 5
\begin{myenum7} \item{Some Text Here} \end{myenum7} & : & \blindtext.\\
\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

This resulted in this[output1][[image: ][1]]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S1tj8.png)[[image: output2]][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UHLfN.png)

My questions are:

1. I know with \newlist and \setlist, I can create a custumized enumerated list in first column, but is there any more elegant way? `answered`
2. How can I produce a table span multiple pages with combination of numbered list in first column, some text in the second column, `:` symbol in third column, and numbered list in fourth column and keep them vertically align?
3. And how can I reduced unnecessary vertical space between \section and the text after it? `answered`

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: are you sure that you want a longtable here? It is almost always better to use a list rather than a tabular layout for such things (apart from anything else, that allows page breaking within an item)

Comment: Why are you using so many different `enumerate`-like envirfonments?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I not sure myself, but that was the best I can came up with, because it was a part of a bit complex report and I just follow the default format provided.

Comment: @Mico I used to work with simple tabular with enumerate/itemize, but I find it difficult to insert an automatic numbering for the first column. That is why i used different set of \newlist and \setlist for each individual numbering list. :(

Answer (score 1):

If the only reason for using a custom `enumerate` environment is to automatically insert a counter in the first column, I suggest you proceed as follows. Observe that both the `longtable` and the `tabular` environments feature an column (of type `N`) which is programmed increment the counter and then print it out immediately.

Note that one can easily cross-reference specific rows via the usual `\label`-`\ref` mechanism.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt]{article}
\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{array,longtable,etoolbox,lipsum}
\setlength\extrarowheight{2pt} % for a more open "look" of tabular material
\newcolumntype{P}[1]{p{#1\textwidth}}

\newcounter{rownum}
\newcolumntype{N}{>{\refstepcounter{rownum}\therownum}l}
% Automate resetting of counter to 0 at the start of a tabular-like env.:
\AtBeginEnvironment{tabular}{\setcounter{rownum}{0}}
\AtBeginEnvironment{tabular*}{\setcounter{rownum}{0}}
\AtBeginEnvironment{tabularx}{\setcounter{rownum}{0}}
\AtBeginEnvironment{longtable}{\setcounter{rownum}{0}}

\begin{document}

\begingroup  % localize the following settings
\setlength\tabcolsep{0pt} % <--- important
\setlength\LTleft{0pt} \setlength\LTright{0pt}

\begin{longtable}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}} N P{0.32} P{0.63}} 
   % rel. column widths of the "P" columns should sum to no more than 0.95.
\hline
\endfirsthead
\hline
\endlastfoot

& Some text here      & \lipsum*[1] \\[1ex]
& Some more text here & \lipsum*[2] \\

\end{longtable}
\endgroup


\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{@{} N lll @{}}
\hline
& a & b & c \\
& d & e & f \\
\label{row:last}& g & h & i \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}

%% Create a cross-reference to the final row:
\noindent
A cross-reference to row \ref{row:last}.
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you @Mico for the solution, just a clarification, when the text is replaced by `\enumerate` environment it will create additional vertical space and will not inline with the rest of the items (it only happen if the 3rd column was replaced by `\begin{enumerate}`)

Comment: @BramSetyadjiMadusuyatno - I suspect I haven't fully understood what you're trying to achieve. Would you mind editing your posting and stating explicitly what you are looking to do?

Comment: Nevermind... I've find the solution using `\vspace*{-\baselineskip}` before `\begin{enumerate}` :) Sorry for my laziness, Thank you!