# Table cell centering

Tags: tables

I'm learning to use LaTeX with Overleaf and I cannot solve this problem.

I want to center both vertically and horizontally the first row, while increasing the space between lines and adding enumerate. Everything I try doesn´t work.

This is the code:

```
\begin{table}
\begin{center}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{10pt} % Default value: 6pt
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5} % Default value: 1
\begin{tabular}{p{8cm}}
\toprule
\centerline{\textbf{Titleeeeeeeeeee}}  \\
\hline
\begin{enumerate}
  \item aaaaaaaaaaaa
  \item bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb
  \item cccccccccccccccccccccc
  \item ddddddddd
  \item eeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee
\end{enumerate}\\
\toprule
\end{tabular}
\caption{\label{tab:xxxxx} xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx}
\end{center}
\end{table}
```

And this is the result,

[image]

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)! Please help us (and also you) and add a minimal working example ([MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that)), that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: see http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/347253/.

Comment: Why do you use `\toprule` for the line at the bottom of the table instead og `\bottomrule`? Regarding the centered alignment in the first row, you might want to use `\multicolumn` or `\makecell` instead of `\centerline`.

Answer (score 1):

That-a-way?
Note you shouldn't use the `center`environment within `table`, as it adds unwanted vertical spacing. Use the `\centering` directive instead. The `makecell` package allows for line breaks in standard cells and a common formatting for cells introduced by `\makecell`  or `\thead`. Last, you can define ‘cell gapes’  which are vertical spacing added at the top and bottom of cells with the `\makegapedcells` command.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{makecell, booktabs}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\renewcommand{\theadfont}{\normalsize\bfseries}
\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\compress}{\@minipagetrue}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\centering
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{10pt} % Default value: 6pt
\setcellgapes{10pt}\makegapedcells
\begin{tabular}{>{\compress}p{8cm}}
\toprule
\thead{Titleeeeeeeeeee} \\
\midrule
\begin{enumerate}[after=\vspace*{-\dimexpr\baselineskip + \partopsep}, wide=0pt, leftmargin=*]
  \item aaaaaaaaaaaa
  \item bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb
  \item cccccccccccccccccccccc
  \item ddddddddd
  \item eeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee
\end{enumerate}\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\caption{\label{tab:xxxxx} xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]