# Itemizing in LATEX table

Tags: tables

I am trying to create a table that involves a lot of text, and therefore requires enumerating. The problem, I can't get it to do it. What am I doing wrong? The table is one of several tables that includes a summary of several points. My code is as follows (I have attached a picture of the table layout I want):

```
\begin{sidewaystable}
\begin{center}
    \caption{Major Enhanced Oil Recovery Processes }
    \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|}
    \hline &&\\
    \textbf{Process} &
    \textbf{Description} &
    \textbf{Advantages} &
    \textbf{Disadvantages}\\
    &&\\
    \hline
    &&\\
    \textbf{CSI}
    & 1 
    & 2
    & 3
    \\
    &&\\
    \hline
    &&\\
    \textbf{SAGD}
    & 1
    & 2
    & 3
    \\
    &&\\
    \hline
    &&\\
    \textbf{CO$_2$}
    & 1
    & 2
    & 3
    \\
    &&\\
    \hline
    &&\\
    \textbf{N$_2$}
    & 1
    & 2
    & 3
    \\
    &&\\
    \hline
    &&\\
    \textbf{Surfactant}
    & 1
    & 2
    & 3
    \\
    &&\\
    \hline
    &&\\
    \textbf{Alkaline}
    & 1
    & 2
    & 3
    \\
    &&\\
    \hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{center}

\end{sidewaystable}
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Have you tried to use `\textbullet` for the marking points? Can you please complete your code snippet to be compilable? Then we do not have to guess what you are doing ...

Comment: see http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/347253/   or  tex.stackexchange.com/questions/382817/   or tex.stackexchange.com/questions/338003/   or ... welcome to tex.se!

Comment: Do you have any news for us? Is your issue solved? How?